# Why doesn't Firefox Quantum show equations in Wikipedia in MathML any more?

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum, mathml

In my Wikipedia account I've set the math appearance preference to *MathML with SVG or PNG fallback (recommended for modern browsers and accessibility tools)*, and it worked fine for a long time...

... until recently when Firefox was upgraded to the Quantum version, and I notice that all the expressions are now in PNG fallbacks instead of beautiful MathML like before.

I'm using Windows 10. Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any examples of pages that previously looked good?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't take any screenshots in the past. However the main reasons I prefer in MathML are better zoom capability (as I'm setting dpi at 125%) and fast loading time. I only found some questions regarding MathML like these https://askubuntu.com/q/716016/253474 https://askubuntu.com/q/784841/253474

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the Wikipedia help article ''[Displaying a Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Native_MathML)'', MathML in Firefox requires the [Native MathML](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/native-mathml/) extension.

I suggest that you check that you have this extension installed and enabled.

Comment: previously it worked without any add-on. I also tried that add-on before asking this but it didn't work. I've just reinstalled it and now it works fine

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc as far as i am aware, Firefox has native MathML support built in. The add-on simply rewrites formulas from other notations in MathML to take advantage of this. Wikipedia does not output formulas in MathML, so you need the client to rewrite it before rendering. As to why it changed, perhaps the plugin was previously bundled into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to enable MathML on wikipedia with firefox. Normally, with default settings, wikipedia **does** put the mathml element into the page, just above where it puts the 'backup' svg. I put backup in quotes, since by default the mathml is hidden and the svg is shown.

Of course you can just get the aforementioned extension. But you might not want to. Note that the extension does a bunch of other stuff, not all of which can be disabled.

My method has only been very briefly tested, and is for **people with uBlock Origin**. It may be possible also with other adblock extensions with similar capabilities.

Simply add these lines to your list of static filters.

```
en.wikipedia.org##.mwe-math-mathml-a11y:style(clip: auto !important;overflow: visible !important;position: static !important;width: auto !important;height: auto !important;opacity: 1 !important;display: inherit !important;)
en.wikipedia.org##[class^=mwe-math-fallback-image]
```

This is just the relevent css taken from the Native MathML extension.

I should note, however, that personally I prefer the look of latex, so I use mathjax dynamically loaded (with a userscript) after getting the latex code out of the img tag (I think it's the alt text for the img).

Comment: another option would be to add the css (from https://github.com/fred-wang/webextension-native-mathml/blob/master/content-scripts/mediawiki.css) to your custom css page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MyPage/common.css)

*but* you'd need to only enable it when using firefox, otherwise it'll hide the fallback image in browsers that don't support mathml (maybe wrap the css in a @supports block containing some firefox-exclusive css property?)